# How to Optimize Combined Graphical Operations?

Tags: qt, rendering

Here is a Scenario, A series of operations that I will call for painting,

QPainter p(this);

1). p.fillRect(0,0,320,240, RED_COLOR)

2)  p.drawLine(0,0,100,100, BLUE_COLOR)

3)  p.fillRect(0,0,320,240, YELLOW_COLOR)

Now I want that painter should not draw first FillRect Function. 
It should not draw line.
It should only perform last operation.

Is there any way to achive this optimization in Qt.

Is this type of drawing/painting optimizations are supported by any library?

Comment: Are you looking to reimplement the QPainter.fillRect function ? Qt already has multiple ways of actually doing the drawing. The question is really hard to understand

Comment: @HHarald Scheirich: Question Modified for ease of understanding

Comment: The answer to your question is 'no'.

Comment: @ypnos : why No? Is there any library which performs this type of optimizations?

Comment: No because it would be very inefficient to sort out which operations affect which pixels to gain the understanding needed for this kind of operations. In general you may claim that the actual drawing of the rect and the line is not much more complex than determining the pixels covered by them, if you take into account also the possibility to alter the transformation matrix in between. Also the colors may have alpha values, and so on. Therefore I don't know any library that would do that kind of operation and the answer is 'no'. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no.  However, off-screen rendering is generally fast and Qt double-buffers widgets for you.  [Painting to QImage or QPixmap](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/paintsystem-devices.html) can also be done in non-GUI threads, so you can multi thread the painting.  QPixmaps also have the advantage of [QPixmapCache](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qpixmapcache.html).

You could do the optimization yourself depending on how the paint commands are created.  If you know all the commands at the time you start, you could use a stack of shapes and if the top of the stack is contained within the last created shape, don't draw it.

---

However, you should profile this section of code to see if it really is gaining anything.  Premature micro-optimization often leads to wasted effort.

I would start with offscreen rendering (multi threaded if possible), if that really is too slow, try other steps.  However, in most cases the standard paint methods will be fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can always paint your complex scene into a QPixmap and then only blit that pixmap when painting happens. Of course, it needs to be updated when the scene changes (e.g. it is resized, a state something in it changed, etc.)

Comment: Does not answer the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for display list rendering optimization, specifically occlusion test in your example, then I don't think Qt itself provides such function.

You may want to see if OpenGL has this capability. If so, then maybe drawing to a [QGLWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qglwidget.html) will get what you want?